# How to schedule AWS Lambda to run with different frequency based on the hour

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, scheduling, frequency

Is it possible to trigger lambda function with different frequency throughout the day, based on the hour?
For exmaple I would like to trigger lambda function hourly 6am-12pm and then once per 6 hours 12pm-6am.

Bold hours are when I would like to trigger lambda:
**12am** 1am 2am 3am 4am 5am **6am 7am 8am 9am 10am 11am 12pm** 1pm 2pm 3pm 4pm 5pm **6pm** 7pm 8pm 9pm 10pm 11pm

Time zone is irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup 2 CloudWatch event rules to trigger lambdas with different frequency. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html